# JTextPane read from text file

Tags: java, swing, oop, file-io, jtextpane

I have a .txt file which has 3 lines

My GUI code is

```
txtpnEmergencyAmbulanceAnd = new JTextPane();
     try {
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileNumbers);

            // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            while((lineNumbers = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    txtpnEmergencyAmbulanceAnd.setText(lineNumbers);
        }
            // Always close files.
            bufferedReader.close();            
        }

     catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Unable to open file '" + 
                fileNumbers + "'");                
        }
     catch(IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(
                "Error reading file '" 
                + fileNumbers + "'");      
     }
```

However what prints into my GUI is only the last line. I'm trying to print out all three lines
I have also included this as a global

```
String fileNumbers = "numbers.txt";

String lineNumbers = "";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setText` does exactly, sets the components text to the value you pass it, discarding any content it previously had.

Instead try using [`JTextPane#read(Reader, Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object))

FYI: You might want to take a closer look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) in order to manage your resources better

Comment: `txtpnEmergencyAmbulanceAnd.read(bufferedReader, fileNumbers);`

This however prints only my last two lines.

Comment: Apparently adding an empty line ontop of my first line in the .txt file fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you overwrite the contents of your `JTextPane` on every run.

Quick and dirty solution:

```
txtpnEmergencyAmbulanceAnd.setText(txtpnEmergencyAmbulanceAnd.getText() + lineNumbers);
```

Comment: `String` concatenation is not a good idea in a loop, sure it's three lines, but using a `StringBuilder` would not just be good practice, but in this case, it would also be more efficient, as you're not having to convert the `Document` to a `String` as well

Comment: You must have managed to overlook the "Quick and dirty" prefix of my "solution".

Comment: As a forum of professionals, we really should avoid "quick and dirty" as it leads to bad habits, which then need to be beaten out of people...save the bruises ;)

Comment: This works but it does not separate the three lines. It gives the three lines in one.

Comment: Yes, because you have to take care of line breaks on your own.